# Script mdf 2012 to SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a mdf file, but its seem to detach by `Sql-Server 2012`. But I am using `Sql-Server 2008`, so I can not attach this mdf file.

```
error 706 ...
```

Anybody, who use sql server 2012 can help me to generate script to sql for me?

Information:

> MDF file -> SQL SERVER 2012 Want to genarate script to sql file to use
>   in SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Download; https://app.box.com/s/lxyjsu3parrtpswjrfses6hbo8san33j

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your DB -> Tasks -> Generate scripts and then choose needed tables, path for script and settings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Sql Server Management Studio

Right Click your Database from where you want to create the scripts and follow the path shown in the screen shot.

[image]

Make sure in Advance options you select the following option.

[image]